# Coloring a tab in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

We have a situation where we want to color the tabs for the worksheets using openpyxl.  Is there a way to do this within the library?  Or, has anyone found a way to do this external to the library (i.e. by extension or something similar)?

Comment: Seems like no way to color tabs via openpyxl, consider using xlsxwriter.

Comment: One can do this with openpyxl now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the tab color in a new Excel file using the [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) Python module. Here is an example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('tab_colors.xlsx')

# Set up some worksheets.
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set tab colours
worksheet1.set_tab_color('red')
worksheet2.set_tab_color('green')
worksheet3.set_tab_color('#FF9900')  # Orange

# worksheet4 will have the default colour.
workbook.close()
```

[image: Coloured tabs in Excel worksheet using Python]

Comment: Is it this thing is possible with xlwt or with any default python lib?

Answer (score 14):

You can color the tabs with openpyxl by using RRGGBB color code for sheet_properties.tabColor property:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('My_Color_Title')
ws.sheet_properties.tabColor = 'FFFF00'

wb.save('My_book_with_Yellow_Tab.xlsx')
```

[image]