# How, I can change Excel sheet tab background colour by python

Tags: python, python-2.5, xlwt

I am generating report and want to highlight the tab when its fails.

```
import xlrd    
import xlwt

wb = Workbook()    
add_result = wb.add_sheet(req_id[req_num])    
wb.save("report_name.xls")
```

Comment: I found something but that will to use another lib, that is xlsxwriter (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667750/coloring-a-tab-in-openpyxl). But, I prefer use less lib as much as possibe.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting the tab: coloring the tab or just making the sheet active?

Comment: I mean colouring the tab..

Comment: Got it, I bet there is no way to do it via xlwt.

Comment: How about using from win32com.client import Dispatch ?

Comment: Well, if you are on windows and it's ok for you to "speak" with excel via COM - then sure, it may work.

Comment: Yes, I am on windows, I give a try ..Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xl = Dispatch( "Excel.Application")

xl.Visible = False

xlFile = "C:/tab_colour.xls"

wkb = xl.Workbooks.Open(xlFile)

sheet = xl.Worksheets.Item("SVP INFO")

sheet.Tab.Color = 255

wkb.Save()

wkb.Close()

xl.Quit()

xl = None
```